# Can some body help me understand some parts of a schematic circuit?

Tags: pic, sensor

I have [image: this] circuit schematic, and I do not understand what are the parts in red circles and what do they do. 
The schematics are from a movement sensor using a PIC micro controller, infrared LED and an infrared receiver

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The part at the top is a 2-point terminal block.

[image]

The part at the bottom is a barrel jack with switch.

[image: https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/1/0/8/00119-03-L.jpg]

Both are very common parts, but there are many, many different types that would the same schematic symbol. They are just connectors- the first for wires to board (contacts on a relay), the second from something like a wall plug power supply (to the on-board regulator).